# Link error when compiling opencv from source when including ffmpeg compiled from source

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been stuck on this problem for weeks.

I'm trying to build opencv on a raspberry pi 4 with x264 support. To do this I need to include ffmpeg, and also build that from source.

However when compiling opencv, I'm consistently getting these linker errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_context_defaults3'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_lockmgr_register'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_register_all'
```

I'm new to Linux, so I'm not exactly sure how to get started troubleshooting this. I believe I have ffmpeg correctly compiled and installed.

Here's the steps I use:

**Configure ffmpeg:**

```
sudo ./configure \
--prefix=/usr \
--extra-ldflags="-latomic" \
--enable-shared \
--extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' \
--ld=g++ \
--enable-gpl \
--disable-debug \
--enable-nonfree \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-omx \
--enable-omx-rpi \
--enable-gnutls \
--enable-libfreetype \
--enable-libmp3lame
```

**Then build it:**
sudo make -j4

**Then install it as a package:** (so opencv cmake will detect it)

```
sudo checkinstall -y --deldoc=yes --pkgversion=9999 --pkgname=ffmpeg
```

**Then configure opencv** (ffmpeg is detected)

```
sudo cmake ../opencv_sources -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH= $PWD/../opencv_contrib/modules \
-D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
-D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
-D BUILD_TESTS=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS='-latomic -L/usr/lib' \
-D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D CPU_BASELINE=NATIVE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/opencv_build" \
-D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON
```

**Then build opencv:**

```
sudo make -j4
```

And this is where I get linking errors.

I checked in /usr/lib and the .so files appear to be there:

```
ls /usr/lib | grep libav

libavcodec.a
libavcodec.so
libavcodec.so.59
libavcodec.so.59.4.101
libavdevice.a
libavdevice.so
libavdevice.so.59
libavdevice.so.59.0.100
libavfilter.a
libavfilter.so
libavfilter.so.8
libavfilter.so.8.1.103
libavformat.a
libavformat.so
libavformat.so.59
libavformat.so.59.4.101
libavutil.a
libavutil.so
libavutil.so.57
libavutil.so.57.3.100
```

How do check where opencv is looking when linking? And is there a way I can check the shared libraries that ffmpeg generated to make sure they work?

The ffmpeg version is: git-2021-08-10-c245963

And opencv is 4.5.3-dev

Comment: This kind of problem is mostly related with the needed dependencies. You probably didnt install the dependency libraries before opencv installation. You may have a look at the description part of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyHbV3XhBoM) and installing dependincies and rebuild the opencv and re-install it again

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I agree, but I believe the dependency in this case is ffmpeg, which I am also compiling from source. I think it's some combination of incorrect configurations, incorrect installation, or incompatible versions, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it. I've been shooting in the dark for a long time to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

I was compiling the master branch of ffmpeg. This version removed some deprecated functions and was incompatible with my opencv version. Or at least the build tests failed. By switching to the release/4.4 branch and repeating my previous build steps I was able to successfully build opencv.

**Details:**

I was able to determine that it's not a linking problem. I wrote a short program that calls avcodec_get_context_defaults3(...), as well as avcodec_version(), which is another function that should be in there. Upon linking libavcodec.so, the avcodec_version() is found, but avcodec_get_context_defaults3() is not. Therefore I believe this is a version compatibility issue between ffmpeg and opencv.

I then  confirmed that the function was removed from ffmpeg. The latest version does not have it, old versions do. I used git's search function and found this commit:

```
Author: Andreas Rheinhardt <andreas.rheinhardt@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 25 20:37:24 2021 +0100

    avcodec: Remove deprecated avcodec_get_context_defaults3

    Deprecated in 04fc8e24a091ed1d77d7a3c0cbcfe60baec19a9f.

    Signed-off-by: Andreas Rheinhardt <andreas.rheinhardt@gmail.com>
    Signed-off-by: James Almer <jamrial@gmail.com>
```

I switched to the release/3.4 branch of FFMPEG and repeated the steps. But that was missing some other things. I repeated the steps a 3rd time with release/4.4 and that worked.

The command I used to download the correct branch was this:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg --branch release/4.4 --depth 1 ffmpeg_sources
```